# How to calculate count using groupby function in Java 8?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

How to use groupby with counting function ?

I have following data and I want following output :

[image]

Desired output :

```
Stock | TOTAL | INPROGRESS | CANCEL | COMPLETED
-----------------------------------------------
HCL   |     4 |          2 |      1 |        1
TCS   |     5 |          2 |      0 |        2
```

NOTE  : I stored this data in hashmap. Key : OrderId, Value : OrderModel (PairName, staus)

I can achieve with following code. But I want more correct code. Please suggest me if you have other ways.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, Model> test = new HashMap<Integer, Model>();

        Model m1 = new Model("HCL", "Inprogress");
        Model m2 = new Model("HCL", "Cancel");
        Model m3 = new Model("HCL", "Inprogress");
        Model m4 = new Model("HCL", "Completed");

        Model a1 = new Model("TCS", "Inprogress");
        Model a2 = new Model("TCS", "Inprogress");
        Model a3 = new Model("TCS", "Inprogress");
        Model a4 = new Model("TCS", "Completed");
        Model a5 = new Model("TCS", "Completed");

        int count = 1;

        test.put(count++, m1);
        test.put(count++, m2);
        test.put(count++, m3);
        test.put(count++, m4);

        test.put(count++, a1);
        test.put(count++, a2);
        test.put(count++, a3);
        test.put(count++, a4);
        test.put(count, a5);

        Map<String, Model> countPair = new HashMap<String, Model>();

        test.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key:" + k + " Pair:" + v.getName() + " Status:" + v.getStatus()));

        System.out.println(" With Count !!!!");
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        test.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> list.add(e.getValue()));

        // Total
        Map<String, Long> counted = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName, Collectors.counting()));
        counted.forEach((k, v) -> {
            countPair.put(k, new Model.ModelBuilder().setTotal(v).build());
        });

        // Inprogress
        counted = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getStatus().equals("Inprogress"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName, Collectors.counting()));
        counted.forEach((k, v) -> countPair.get(k).setInProgressCount(v));

        // Cancel
        counted = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getStatus().equals("Cancel"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName, Collectors.counting()));
        counted.forEach((k, v) -> countPair.get(k).setCancelCount(v));

        // Completed
        counted = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getStatus().equals("Completed"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName, Collectors.counting()));
        counted.forEach((k, v) -> countPair.get(k).setCompletedCount(v));

        countPair.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Pair : " + k + " : " + v.getTotal() + " , "
                + v.getInProgressCount() + " , " + v.getCancelCount() + " , " + v.getCompletedCount()));

    }
```

Model :

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private String status;

    private long total;
    private long inProgressCount;
    private long completedCount;
    private long cancelCount;

    static class ModelBuilder {
        private long total;
        private long inProgressCount;
        private long completedCount;
        private long cancelCount;

        public ModelBuilder setTotal(long total) {
            this.total = total;
            return this;
        }

        public ModelBuilder setInProgressCount(long inProgressCount) {
            this.inProgressCount = inProgressCount;
            return this;
        }

        public ModelBuilder setCompletedCount(long completedCount) {
            this.completedCount = completedCount;
            return this;
        }

        public ModelBuilder setCancelCount(long cancelCount) {
            this.cancelCount = cancelCount;
            return this;
        }

        public Model build() {
            return new Model(this);
        }

    }

    public Model(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        this.total = modelBuilder.total;
        this.inProgressCount = modelBuilder.inProgressCount;
        this.completedCount = modelBuilder.completedCount;
        this.cancelCount = modelBuilder.cancelCount;
    }

    public Model(String name, String status) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }
//getter and setter
}
```

Comment: "*I can achieve with following code. But I want more correct code*" So does your code work or doesn't it? If it doesn't work, can you really say that you've "achieved" your goal? I suppose you what you actually want is more *concise* code or something?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```java
List<Model> test = Arrays.asList(
        new Model("HCL", "Inprogress"),
        new Model("HCL", "Cancel"),
        new Model("HCL", "Inprogress"),
        new Model("HCL", "Completed"),
        new Model("TCS", "Inprogress"),
        new Model("TCS", "Inprogress"),
        new Model("TCS", "Inprogress"),
        new Model("TCS", "Completed"),
        new Model("TCS", "Completed")
);

Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = test.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getName,
                     Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getStatus,
                         Collectors.counting())));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
HCL={Cancel=1, Completed=1, Inprogress=2}
TCS={Completed=2, Inprogress=3}
```

Shouldn't be a problem using that `result` object to produce the desired output, since all the heavy lifting has already been done.

```java
System.out.println("Stock | TOTAL | INPROGRESS | CANCEL | COMPLETED");
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> nameEntry : result.entrySet()) {
    String name = nameEntry.getKey();
    Map<String, Long> statusCounts = nameEntry.getValue();
    long inprogress = statusCounts.getOrDefault("Inprogress", 0L);
    long cancel     = statusCounts.getOrDefault("Cancel"    , 0L);
    long completed  = statusCounts.getOrDefault("Completed" , 0L);
    System.out.printf("%-5s | %5d | %10d | %6d | %8d%n", name,
                      inprogress + cancel + completed,
                      inprogress, cancel, completed);
}
```

*Output*

```
Stock | TOTAL | INPROGRESS | CANCEL | COMPLETED
-----------------------------------------------
HCL   |     4 |          2 |      1 |        1
TCS   |     5 |          3 |      0 |        2
```

*Note:* Comparing that to the "Desired output" in the question, we observe that the question example is wrong, since `TCS, INPROGRESS` is 3, not 2.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Andreas on the part about best stream solution.
But becouse you tagged it with performance i would say that we should compare execution times so i did compare vijayk solution with Andreas solution and with solution without stream.

Here are the results for 9 objects in list:

```
Total execution with stream in ms: 7.642649ms
Total execution with for each in ms: 0.037637ms
Total execution with Andreas stream in ms: 0.392906ms
foreach was faster than vijayk by : 203.06211972261337
Andreas was faster than vijayk by : 19.451596565081726
foreach was faster than Andreas by : 10.439354890134707
```

Here are the results for 18 000 000 objects in list:

```
Total execution with stream in ms: 703.025082ms
Total execution with for each in ms: 278.319758ms
Total execution with Andreas stream in ms: 504.190017ms
foreach was faster than vijayk by : 2.5259618183485197
Andreas was faster than vijayk by : 1.3943653350835783
foreach was faster than Andreas by : 1.8115494948080546
```

Then I changed stream to parallel stream and results look like that

For 9 objects in list:

```
Total execution with stream in ms: 20.937947ms
Total execution with for each in ms: 0.042329ms
Total execution with Andreas stream in ms: 0.496791ms
foreach was faster than vijayk by : 494.64780646837863
Andreas was faster than vijayk by : 42.14638952799064
foreach was faster than Andreas by : 11.736421838455906
```

For 18 000 000 objects in list:

```
Total execution with stream in ms: 476.563756ms
Total execution with for each in ms: 278.438998ms
Total execution with Andreas stream in ms: 302.730519ms
foreach was faster than vijayk by : 1.7115553475738337
Andreas was faster than vijayk by : 1.5742177484259523
foreach was faster than Andreas by : 1.087241805833535
```

For each solution looks like that:

```
for (Model item : list) {
        Model itemToIncrease;
        if (countPair.containsKey(item.getName())) {
            itemToIncrease = countPair.get(item.getName());
        } else {
            countPair.put(item.getName(), item);
            itemToIncrease = item;
        }
        itemToIncrease.increaseTotal();
        switch (item.getStatus()) {
            case "Inprogress":
                itemToIncrease.increaseInProgressCount();
                break;
            case "Cancel":
                itemToIncrease.increaseCancelCount();
                break;
            case "Completed":
                itemToIncrease.increaseCompletedCount();
                break;
        }
}
```

To summ it up i would say that Andreas solution is very good when you have a lot of data